# Trying to learn better lambda coding

Tags: c#, linq

While the following code works fine I was wondering if there a cleaner way to accomplish this with lambda expressions?

```
var counter = 1;

foreach (var item in model)
{
   item.ID = counter++;
}
```

Comment: Linq is basically not designed for updating but for querying data. So this is simply not possible, and not even needed. What is whrong with this nice short code?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Linq != Lambda

Comment: See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a inline Lambda ForEach

```
model.ForEach(x => x.ID = counter++);
```

**Update/Restriction:**

- this will only work when `model` is type `List<>`
- in case of value types the items won't be updated - without an error

Comment: While it is technically correct it worth noting that in many occasions this will be considered as 'bad practice' / 'code smells' etc...

Comment: @fubo, why did you assume that model is a `List`??

Comment: @ASh - you're right, otherwise it won't work or must be `model.ToList().ForEach()` but as Fabjan already pointed out - this was more a technical question about Lambda expressions

Comment: Even if `model` is a list, this code won't work if the items are value-types. (Admittedly, the OP's code fails in that situation too, but at least it would fail with a compiler error; your `ForEach` would appear to work, but the list items wouldn't be updated!)

Comment: @LukeH - thank you. I added your comment into my answer.